Deeplink for app gallery store not working
I'm trying to open the App Gallery store to update my app, but app is not found.
I tried opening other applications with other ids but with no success. Also i tried used "market://details?id=" scheme. AppGallery opens, but no application information is found.
Maybe i need to use an another scheme?
val marketIntent = Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("appmarket://details?id=C107473825")
)

val preferMarketResolveInfo = getAppResolveInfo(
    context = context, 
    intent = marketIntent, 
    packageName = marketDeeplink.preferMarketPackageName
)

val componentName = preferMarketResolveInfo?.let {
    ComponentName(it.activityInfo.packageName, it.activityInfo.name) 
}

marketIntent.setComponent(componentName)

startActivity(marketIntent)

private fun getAppResolveInfo(
    context: Context, 
    intent: Intent, 
    packageName: String?
): ResolveInfo? {
    val allActivitiesForIntent = context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)

    val preferResolveInfo = allActivitiesForIntent.find { resolveInfo ->
        resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName == packageName
    }

    return preferResolveInfo 
}

result
